# Visual Studio Copilot Chat Extension, Code Output too narrow to read

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I have no idea how I ended up like this but am unable to resolve this.

[image]

As you can see the output of the copilot chat extension is too narrow for me to read. But it is there, and the Copy, CreateNewFile and Preview buttons work.

I am using Visual Studio 17.9.0 Preview 2.0 and have a Copilot Individual subscription.
It worked before. I have already tried to delete the .vs folder inside my solution, but that does not seem to be related to the solution but to the global Visual Studio setting.

Do you have any idea how to solve this? Uninstalling and re-installing the extension did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a related ticket about this on the VS community platform, which is resolved [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-Copilot-Chat-extensions-code-boxes-/10364048#T-N10559517), the comment saying that the problem went away by using "GitHub Copilot Chat 0.2.241.22873 &
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.9.0 Preview 2.1" (quoting Kevin Gallahan).